# How to control the access/permission of custom controllers by user-management module?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, migration, yii2-advanced-app

At Yii 1.x, I use user and rights modules for role and permission of user and controllers.

Now, I tried to migrate my projects from Yii 1.x to Yii 2 Advanced. I tried to use [user-management](https://github.com/webvimark/user-management) module, but I'm having issues with how this module manages access/permissions of the custom controllers.

How do I control the access/perminssion of custom controllers with the user-management module in Yii2 to mimic the behavior of the user and rights modules of Yii 1.x?"

Answer (score 0):

In yii2 you can control access in several way  eg: using access filter http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html
or using  an a full Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac

you can use default yii2 RBAC module or extensions Yii2-admin https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin  ... rbac https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-rbac

You can find useful info in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html